# Looping over characters in a string and applying a macro with an additional argument

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3

The following code was kindly provided for me in TeX Chat by @egreg.

This LaTeX 3 code loops over a list of characters, and puts a box around each character. It does not skip whitespace

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\spacechars}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \c_space_tl }
  \tl_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_tl \boxedchar
 }
 \ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\boxedchar}{m}{%
  \framebox[2em]{\strut#1}%
 }

\begin{document}

\spacechars{ab c d}

\end{document}
```

I'd like an enhancement of this code, with a variation of `\spacechars` which allows one to include a width argument that can then be passed to `\framebox`.

But it does not look like `\tl_map_function` will do the job, unless there is some way to pass it a macro which is a version of `boxedchar` where the width argument has been applied (i.e. as in [partial function application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)).

I looked at the functions in the LaTeX 3 interface document, (which is 
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf` on my system), but didn't see anything that looked like it fit the bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily. `;-)`

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\spacechars}{O{1em}m}
 {
  \faheem_spacechars:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\boxedchar}{O{1em}m}
 {
  \faheem_spacechars_box:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__faheem_spacechars_tl
\tl_new:N \l__faheem_spacechars_char_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faheem_spacechars:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__faheem_spacechars_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__faheem_spacechars_tl { ~ } { \c_space_tl }
  \tl_map_variable:NNn \l__faheem_spacechars_tl \l__faheem_spacechars_char_tl
   { \faheem_spacechars_box:nV { #1 } \l__faheem_spacechars_char_tl }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faheem_spacechars_box:nn
 {
  \framebox[#1]{\strut #2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \faheem_spacechars_box:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\spacechars{ab c d}

\spacechars[2em]{ab c d}

\end{document}
```

The trick is `\tl_map_variable:NNn`.

[image]

Comment: For those wondering why the `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` call is needed (I was among them), this is because `\tl_map_variable:NNn` considers the token list as a list of *items* as opposed to a list of *tokens* (the difference is explained at the start of the `l3tl` chapter of [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf)). egreg is a genius. :)